# sftp permissions and group

Tags: sftp

I use sftp to backup my laptop (Ubuntu 18.10) onto a server (Ubuntu 18.04) on my local network. Suddenly something has gone wrong with the permissions on the server and I started getting access denied warnings. My username on the server also lost membership of the sudoers group. I added the user back into the sudoers group but cannot get the access to the backup folder without running `sudo chmod -R 777`. Obviously, for security reasons, I need to have at least 775 permissions on this file but I don't know what user to add to what group to achieve this.

EDIT I tried adding the backup folder owner to the ssh group but that didn't work.

Information requested:

```
~$ ls -l /home/biergarten 
   total 1172 
   drwxrwxr-x 2 biergarten ssh 1167360 Feb 6 00:27 BackupLaptopSSD
   drwxrwxr-x 2 biergarten ssh 20480 Apr 23 09:20 BackupTuxedo
   -rwxrwxr-x 1 biergarten ssh 58 Oct 20 2016 delPhotos.sh
   -rwxrwxr-x 1 biergarten ssh 131 Dec 14 2016 FTP_TEST123.txt


~$ groups biergarten ssh
```

Comment: post the outputs of 
`ls -l /path/to/your/backups` and `groups` - as the user on the server

Comment: ~$ ls -l /home/biergarten
total 1172
drwxrwxr-x 2 biergarten ssh 1167360 Feb  6 00:27 BackupLaptopSSD
drwxrwxr-x 2 biergarten ssh   20480 Apr 23 09:20 BackupTuxedo
-rwxrwxr-x 1 biergarten ssh      58 Oct 20  2016 delPhotos.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 biergarten ssh     131 Dec 14  2016 FTP_TEST123.txt

Comment: ~$ groups
biergarten ssh

Comment: I've added the details you provided to your question. Please check if I've done so correctly.

Comment: Correct, thanks. I should have done that but, in my defence, it was getting late and I'd been working on this problem for a few hours. :-(

Comment: It seems that this is a permissions bug with Deja Dup https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/duplicity/+bug/1770929 I can only save a backup now if the server directory has 777 permissions

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to `chown` the directory back to your user  & the appropriate group.

```
sudo chown -R your-user:appropriate-group /path/to/backups
```

Then you need to investigate how your user got dropped from the sudo group!

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but still cannot backup with Deja-Dup and 'sftp://192.168.1.9/home/backup/' And a funny thing happened, after adding the user to the ssh group and re-booting, the user was removed from the sudoers group. I am 100% sure the user was in sudoers before the chown command because I ran it fron the users account.

Comment: I had something similar happen once upon a time... perhaps worth double checking your syntax: `usermod -G groupname -a username`